# Finding coinciding poles of gamma functions

Tags: logic, algorithms

I have a question about checking the poles of $\Gamma(b_j+\beta_js)$. There are array of b values and array of $\beta$ values, and in order to check if the poles are simple, i need to check
$\beta_j(b_i+k)\neq \beta_i(b_j+l),\quad (i\neq j;\ k,l=0,1,2,\dots;\ \beta_j,\beta_i\in \mathbb{R}_+;\ b_i,b_j\in\mathbb{C})$.
I am not sure if there is an algorithm that checks the condition below in finite time.
$$\beta_1(b_2+k)\neq \beta_2(b_1+l),\quad (k,l=0,1,2\dots;\ \beta_1,\beta_2\in \mathbb{R}_+;\ b_1,b_2\in\mathbb{C})$$
If the problem was this
$$\beta(b_2+k)\neq \beta(b_1+l),\quad (k,l=0,1,2,\dots;\ \beta\in \mathbb{R}_+;\ b_1,b_2\in\mathbb{C})$$
and if we assume that the real part of $b1$ is bigger than the real part of $b2$ then we would simply set $l=0$ and starting from $k=0$ we would increase $k$ by one in each iteration and stop when
$\beta(b_2+k)>=\beta b_1$, at that point, if $\beta(b_2+k)=\beta b_1$ then the condition is violated, but if $\beta(b_2+k)>\beta b_1$ then condition is not violated and we know that it can't be violated, no need to check for different $k$ and $l$ values. We can create a similar algorithm if $\beta_1$ is divisible by $\beta_2$ or vice versa. However, i can't find a stopping condition for the algorithm that checks the other condition. The algorithm will take $\beta_1,b_2,\beta_2,b_1$ as input, and will check if the condition is satisfied for all values of $k$ and $l$, $k$ and $l$ can be any natural number